# How to copy an element text, In Selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

my code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('example.com')


sctitle = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('h1')
scp = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//article[@id='the-post']//p[3]")[2].text
```

the goal is selenium select and copy the h1 title tag, Than in a new tab paste in in the form. 
i have problem with the copying and pasting it. when i want to paste it, Nothing happends.
i use this command for paste:

```
browser.execute_script("window.open('');")
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[2])
browser.get('https://www.sitea.com')
elem = browser.find_element_by_class_name('TextArea__textArea')
elem.send_keys(sctitle.text)
```

Comment: Store the actual string of `sctitle.text` as an object instead and use that for `elem.send_keys`.  e.g. `sctext = sctitle.text; ... elem.send_keys(sctext)`

Comment: i already try this, but nothing happens and the driver stopped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the following to find only single element. `find_elements` returns a list so `.text` method doesn't work.

`sctitle = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('h1')`